# How to configure sentry so it tracks only specific component of React application?

Tags: sentry

Initially I thought that sentry gathers only those errors, which were proccessed with Sentry.captureException, so I created ErrorBoundary around my component, and when error inside of it happens, it triggers Sentry.captureException. But somewhy I get all the errors that occur inside my application, and it doesn't matter if I used captureException or not. So could you explain to me, why do need captureException then and how to disable gathering errors from the whole application? My Sentry.Init is simple, it contains only dsn.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.